# Bootstrap align elements inside col

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, sass

I Need help to fix the problem, I need to center the content inside the column in bootstrap4, please find my code below :

```css
@import '../../styles/global/_variables.sass' .concept-area background-image: url("../../../assets/images/conceptBG.jpg") height: 140px background-position: center background-repeat: no-repeat background-size: cover .title font-family: Raleway font-size: 36px font-weight: 300 font-style: italic font-stretch: normal line-height: 1.03 letter-spacing: 1.8px text-align: left color: $base-gold .btn-discover width: 263px height: 50px box-shadow: 20px 20px 60px 0 rgba(0,
0,
0,
0.4) background-color: $base-gold border-radius: 0 !important color: #ffffff line-height: 0.95 font-size: 20px font-family: Raleway
```

```html
<section class="concept-area">
  <div class=" h-100 ">
    <div class="row h-100 justify-content-center align-items-center">
      <div class="col-md-6 concept-text ">
        <p class="title">Des chèques cadeaux pour <br> des soirées privilèges</p>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-6 text-center">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-discover">DECOUVRIR</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
```

the button is centred well but I can't understand why the p tag with class "title" could not be centred !!

Comment: `.title` has `text-align: left;` _ try changing or removing this

Comment: where is your `container`?

Comment: Why don't you use an appropriate tag for a title like h1, h2..?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<section class="concept-area">
    <div class="col-sm-10 offset-sm-1 text-center h-100 ">
    <div class="row h-100 justify-content-center align-items-center">
      <div class="col-md-6 concept-text">
        <p class="title">Des chèques cadeaux pour <br> des soirées privilèges</p>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-6">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-discover">DECOUVRIR</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
```

See if this fixes your issue. I didn't understand from your question if you are looking for title and button to be inline and centered or you want title and button to be on new lines and centered.